# Hibernate Search Automatic Indexing

Tags: performance, search, indexing, hibernate-search

I am working on developing an application which caters to about 100,000 searches everyday. We can safely assume that there are about the same number of updates / insertions / deletions in the database daily. The current application uses native SQL and we intend to migrate it to Hibernate and use Hibernate Search.

As there are continuous changes in the database records, we need to enable automatic indexing. The management has concerns about the performance impact automatic indexing can cause.

It is not possible to have a scheduled batch indexing as the changes in the records have to be available for search as soon as they are changed.

I have searched to look for some kind of performance statistics but have found none.

Can anybody who has already worked on Hibernate Search and faced a similar situation share their thoughts?

Thanks for the help.

Regards,

Shardul.

Answer (score 0):

It might work fine, but it's hard to guess without a baseline. I have experience with even more searches / day and after some fine tuning it works well, but it's impossible to know if that will apply for your scenario without trying it out.
If normal tuning fails and NRT doesn't proof fast enough, you can always shard the indexes, use a multi-master configuration and plug in a distributed second level cache such as Infinispan: all combined the architecture can achieve linear scalability, provided you have the time to set it up and reasonable hardware.

It's hard to say what kind of hardware you will need, but it's a safe bet that it will be more efficient than native SQL solutions. I would suggest to make a POC and see how far you can get on a single node; if the kind of queries you have are a good fit for Lucene you might not need more than a single server. Beware that Lucene is much faster in queries than in updates, so since you estimate you'll have the same amount of writes and searches the problem is unlikely to be in the amount of searches/second, but in the writes(updates)/second and total data(index) size. Latest Hibernate Search introduced an NRT index manager, which suites well such use cases.